# Starting download programmatically from callback in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, internet-explorer

I have an issue when trying to start a download in IE in an angular+node setup.

First, here is my current process:

- Users click on a download button
- It requests a file from the node server
- The node server generates the file, sends it back to the JS controller
- The JS controller generates a URL for that file, and open it as a download

The version I have been using until now looks like this (simplified for the sake of clarity):

```
var self = this;
var invisibleLink = document.getElementById('invisible-link');

this.services.http.post("createPdf", {foo: 'bar}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .then(function(response){
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    invisibleLink.href = fileURL;
    invisibleLink.download = 'myDownloadedFile';
    invisibleLink.click();
  });
```

This works well, it's smooth and everything... in FF and Chrome. In IE(11) I receive an "Error: Access is denied".

Apparently `.download` and/or `.click()` are not accepted, so following other SE questions, I tried to use `window.location`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work either.

Here is what I tried, and the results:

```
window.location.href = fileURL;
// Error: Permission denied

window.location.href = file;
// Opens "http://myurl.com/[object%20Blob]"

window.location = fileURL;
// Error: Access is denied.

window.location = file;
// Opens "http://myurl.com/[object%20Blob]"

window.open= file;
// Nothing happens

window.open= fileURL;
// Nothing happens

// For all tests, using document instead of window had the exact same results
```

I really really really need to trigger the download from the callback, considering:

- 1/ the file is generated, and so there is no existing URL
- 2/ the file generation can take anywhere between 1 and 20s, so anything using a timeOut would be problematic

Is there anyway to start a download from a callback in IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody finding this: the easiest solution ended up being using a module

Using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js):

```
var self = this;

this.services.http.post("createPdf", {foo: 'bar}, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
  .then(function(response){
    var file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    saveAs(file, 'myDownloadedFile');
  });
```

Comment: Have you seen anything for dealing with IE<10?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to cache the data in memory n the server for a short amount of time (maybe just a few minutes), and associate it with a UUID. Then return the UUID from the server, and have the client make another request (this time by navigating to a new URL, not with AJAX) to a URL on the server that takes the UUID as a parameter and sends back the data.